# javascript/nodejs - async code inside while loop which is inside a map array method

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, async-await, promise

I am executing the code block below. For the jsfiddle line, click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nmf4do0y/)

```
async function sleep(time = 1) {
  const sleepMilliseconds = time * 1000 
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`Slept for: ${sleepMilliseconds}ms`)
    }, sleepMilliseconds)
  })
}

async function main() {
  let a = [1,2]
  a.map(async(el)=>{
    let i = 3
    console.log(el,i)
    while(i>0) {
      console.log(el, i, 'main')
      console.log(el, i, await sleep(i))
      i -= 1
    }
  })
}

main()
```

Ideal sequence output would be :-

1. 1,3
2. 1,3, main
3. 1, 3, Slept for: 3000ms
4. 1,2, main
5. 1,2, Slept for: 2000ms
6. 1,1 main
7. 1,1 Slept for: 1000ms
8. 2, 3
9. 2,3, main
10. 2, 3, Slept for: 3000ms
11. 2,2, main
12. 2,2, Slept for: 2000ms
13. 2,1 main
14. 2,1 Slept for : 1000ms

But I am not getting this output. The output which I am getting both the loops are running parallely I suppose. Can someone suggest how to tweak the program to get the desired output. Thanks in advance from our team @realpensive.

I have tried wrapping the map in await promise.all but that doesn't seem to help at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `Array.map` function is handling the iteration synchronously but by introducing a promise inside each iteration that what's inside the promise call is executed asynchonously all while the subsequent iteration is probably already being called. So it's exactly what you say it is, parallel (to an extend). The following has the output you require, since a for loop does actually await the promise.

```
for (const el of a) {   
  let i = 3
  console.log(el,i)
  while(i>0) {
    console.log(el, i, 'main')
    console.log(el, i, await sleep(i))
    i -= 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happenig because map is synchronous in nature while the callback it is receiving is asynchronous. map() is calling the callback using `array a` elements at a faster pace but cb is not able to cope up due to time difference, it is still resolving the promise  i.e., awaiting & is in pending state. It gets resolved after some delay.

As answered by Sam, if you replace map method with any other loop iterable which is not synchronous method, it will provide the desired output.